# AngularJS $scope not working for Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
.controller('MainController',function($scope,$rootScope){
   $scope.Name = "Loading"; // Working okay
   $scope.Email = "Loading"; // Working okay
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
       if(response.status === 'connected'){
        FB.api('/me',{fields:'name,birthday,id,email'},function(response){
          console.log(response.name); // Working okay
          $scope.Name = response.name; // Not Working
          $scope.Email = response.email;  // Not Working
        });
       } else {
        FB.login();
        FB.ui({
            method: 'pagetab',
            redirect_uri: 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=376941409363083&redirect_uri=http://localhost'
        }, function(response){});  
       }
    }); 
});
```

**This Scope Giving Me Issues**
I am already tired on this issue, Anyone Help!

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is the problem you're having?

Comment: Search Google
Search StackOverFlow
Anymore

this problem not solved maybe cause me not focused :3

Comment: Try in $scope.$apply().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope might be updated but angular is not aware of it since the update happens outside of angular's context (i.e. not thru the $http service). Try wrapping the update in an `$apply`

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.Name = response.name;
    $scope.Email = response.email;
});
```